# FCM notification not received when app is killed with multiple Firebase projects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application) and use multiple Firebase projects which are dynamically switched on login. As a result, I had to remove the `google-services` plugin and the `google-services.json` and set the configuration programmatically with `FirebaseApp.initializeApp`. Everything works great so far, but when the app is killed completely and receives a notification, there is an error and the notification is not received:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-NotificationMessageHandler
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 8005
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:184)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzo.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.1.0:120)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzo.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.1.0:1)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.1.0:50)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zze.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.1.0:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

In all other situations I receive the notifications accordingly. With the `google-services` plugin and the `google-services.json` I can receive messages by FCM even when the app is killed, but that's not an option, because I can't switch Firebase projects dynamically using the `google-services` plugin.

I always initialize the FirebaseApp as the default app: `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, configuration)`

Any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: Where are you calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, configuration)`?

Comment: We have a separate controller for switching Firebase projects, which we call when the user attempts to login.

Comment: I don't know... maybe it's too late at this point? Have you tried doing this in a ContentProvider with high priority? (but this force you to init all the Firebase instances before the user login)

Comment: I can login and use different Firebase projects without a problem. I can receive notifications from different Firebase projects as well, if the app is in foreground or background. The only issue is when the app is completely killed (swiped away from minimized apps) and I try to receive a notification.

Comment: In every device you tried?

Comment: I've seen this question multiple time, and sometimes is because of a bad Android implementation by OEM, like here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/368#issuecomment-562846173

Comment: Tried all of these solutions, but they didn't help. I'm pretty sure it is not related to any battery optimization techniques, as it works on the same devices when using the `google-services` plugin.

Comment: @MatPag yes, tried it on 4 different devices (three devices and one emulator) and it happened on all of them

Comment: its not possible if app get killed and completely removed from memory

Comment: Even whats app, intagram wont give notification if you completely removed i.e kill app.

Comment: @ArulMani that's not correct, I've started using `data messages` and I can receive them even when the app was killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data messages` instead of `notification messages` fixed the issue. I can now dynamically switch Firebase projects and receive notifications, even when the app was killed / closed.

More information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Answer (score 0):

You should call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, configuration) in onCreate() of Application

Comment: That's not suitable in my case, because the Firebase project is dynamically chosen on login (depending on the user).

Answer (score 0):

> As per documentation,
>
> Notification Message - FCM automatically displays the message to
>   end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages
>   have a predefined set of user-visible keys and an optional data
>   payload of custom key-value pairs.
>
> Data Message - Client app is responsible for processing data messages.
>   Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.

Here is the full article for [Test FCM Notification with POSTMAN!](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3)